# SSRS bar chart bar spanning multiple axis

Tags: reporting-services, bar-chart

I have a basic bar chart to show number of claims received by month. For most clients it shows normally:

[normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qahxZ.png)

But for some the bars span across multiple axis points.

[bar span](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Ivw.png)

I have formatted the axis so that it spans the previous 13 months from the report month end date as such:

[axis options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdFDI.png)

expression for the minimum interval is:

```
=DateAdd(dateinterval.Month,-13,Parameters!prm_month_end.Value)
```

the axis labels are on auto-fit but disabling them doesn't make a difference. I don't think its my SQL statement but all it is is a simple count of claims by month.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I fixed it. I set the maxpixelpointwidth to 50:

[maxpixelpointwidth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zs3v.png)

[Updated Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75uRy.png)